# xref-find-defnition not finding any definition

Tags: xref

I am a newbie and in this part of the tutorial:

"  More generally, if you want to see a function in its original source
file, you can use the xref-find-definitions function to jump to it.
xref-find-definitions works with a wide variety of languages, not
just Lisp, and C, and it works with non-programming text as well.  For
example, xref-find-definition will jump to the various nodes in the
Texinfo source file of this document (provided that you've run the
`etags' utility to record all the nodes in the manuals that come with
Emacs;
"

M-. doesn't find any definition of functions even though the autocompletion in the call works.
I have no idea how to create a tag table, because the manual just states "etags *inputfile*" but again I have no idea which file i would need to create my tags on. Also find-function doesn't work either, it just states simple.el can't be found which is no surprise because only a simple.elc exists. so it searches for the wrong file by default but i don't know how to change that either. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create tags file in project root first.

Run `etags` in project root to create tags file whose name is `TAGS`.

etags is a command line program bundled with Emacs.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Create-Tags-Table.html for details

These days most people use `ctags` instead of `etags`. Run `ctags -e .` in project root to create tags files.

There are two ctags implementation, Exuberant Ctags and Universal Ctags. Universal Ctags is more actively maintained.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags for details.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer.